# Trouble uploading files and images using HTML Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Now I have this Image Upload form:

**image_upload.html**

```
<form id="image_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    <input id="id_image" type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

The following code is my Django forms.py and views.py to handle the POST request:

**forms.py**

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

**views.py**

```
class MyView(DetailView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("FORM IS VALID!!!");

            # Do Something....
```

Once I upload an image file and submit the form, the data is correctly POSTed to the server, and I get the response "FORM IS VALID!!!".

However, I wanted to add a drag and drop upload functionality, so I added this code:

**image_upload.html**

```
<form id="image_upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    <input id="id_image" type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<div id="image_upload_drop_area">Drop Image Here</div>
```

**upload.js**

```
var drop_area = $("#image_upload_drop_area");
drop_area.bind('drop', drop);

function drop(event) {

    var file = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files [0];
    data = new FormData();
    data.append('image', file);

    $.ajax({
        url: location.href,
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function ( data ) {
            console.log("SENT SUCCESS");
        }
    });
```

This doesn't work. The "data" is definitely sent to the server (I do get the "SENT SUCCESS" message from the server), but not as an input for my "#image_upload_form."

In other words, I'm not getting the "FORM IS VALID!!!" message, meaning that it is not stored in the "request.FILES."

How should I change the javascript code so that the image file is sent as ("#imag_upload_form")'s form data??
(namely the input with the id "#id_image")

Thanks

Comment: whats the code that checks your form is valid?

Comment: @PatrickEvans hm..What do you mean?? Its a Django code

Comment: I don't see a csrf token in your form, which, unless you specifically instruct Django to ignore, will cause your post to fail.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for the comment but I do have the csrf_token :(( The only problem is that the FormData I send is not linked to my #image_upload_form.

Comment: OK. Sounds like your form isn't getting serialized properly before it's posted. What is the value of `data` when logged to the console?

Comment: you have to add the relevant form elements to the FormData variable, `data.append('tokenname', $('#idoftoken').val());` etc.